# Can I mix SingleChildScrollview with Pageview

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, user-interface, androidx

I wanna make simple apps that use SingleChilde Scrollview  with a pageview in flutter like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBepx.jpg)

so I was read an article but I didn't find the article that will able to make my apps.

and this is the list will be able to use on these apps :

https://pastebin.com/c9uGKUE8

the password is (password: kucingidn)

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        padding:  new EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
        itemCount: doa.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          final doaIndonesia = doa[index].toString();
          final doaArab = doa_arab[index].toString();
          final artiIndonesia = arti[index].toString();

          return Card(
            child: Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible( // use flexible
                    child: Text(
                      doa[index],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible( // use flexible
                    child: Text(
                      doa_arab[index],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible( // use flexible
                    child: Text(
                      arti[index],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

anyone can help me, I have a deadline for this

Comment: What you are asking is possible. first try it by yourself and let us know if you got stuck with description and code snippet.

Comment: please see again my question

Comment: Have you started creating the Scrollview and you are stuck somewhere? If yes, can you please paste your code?

Comment: can you please see again my question